# Excel VBA - Opened workbook with wildcard or partial match cannot save as copy

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to open a workbook using a wildcard or partial name match and save a copy with another name.

However, there is an error -

[image]

Always at the " Workbooks(myFolderPath & "" & MyFileName).SaveCopyAs Filename:="NEW NAME.xlsx" " line

Here is my code:

```
Sub GENERATE()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


'If workbook name like "Report Due" then open, if not already opened

Dim MyFileName As Variant
Dim myFolderPath As String

myFolderPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
MyFileName = Dir(myFolderPath & "\" & "Report Due*.xlsx")

If MyFileName <> "" Then
    Workbooks.Open (myFolderPath & "\" & MyFileName)
End If

Workbooks(myFolderPath & "\" & MyFileName).SaveCopyAs Filename:="NEW NAME.xlsx"
Workbooks(myFolderPath & "\" & MyFileName).Close SaveChanges:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I'd be happy to see what's wrong! Many thanks!

Comment: Try `Filename:=myFolderPath & "\NEW NAME.xlsx"` ?

Comment: When using `SaveCopyAs` it's safer to provide the full path and not just the file name, to ensure the file ends up where you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a reference to the workbook when you open it, then you shouldn't need to use it's name to reference when saving the copy.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GENERATE()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim MyFileName As Variant
Dim myFolderPath As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'If workbook name like "Report Due" then open, if not already opened

    myFolderPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
    MyFileName = Dir(myFolderPath & "\" & "Report Due*.xlsx")

    If MyFileName <> "" Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myFolderPath & "\" & MyFileName)
        wb.SaveCopyAs Filename:="NEW NAME.xlsx"
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It worked as I intended!